# HTTPS proxy and threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, https, proxy

I am writing proxy that will be placed in the middle of communications between Browser and Website and does not care about content of HTTPS data, it just translates everything from browser to website and back.
Here is a part of code that works (streams are NetworkStreams):

```
while(true)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        do
        {
            int length = (tcpclientBrowser.Available > 0) ? (tcpclientBrowser.Available) : (0);
            byte[] buff = new byte[length];
            if (length != 0) streamBrowser.Read(buff, 0, length);
            ms.Write(buff, 0, length);
        } while (tcpclientBrowser.Available > 0);
        byte[] dataRec = ms.ToArray();
        if (dataRec.Length != 0) streamSite.Write(dataRec, 0, dataRec.Length);
    }

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        do
        {
            int length = (tcpclientSite.Available > 0) ? (tcpclientSite.Available) : (0);
            byte[] buff = new byte[length];
            if (length != 0) streamSite.Read(buff, 0, length);
            ms.Write(buff, 0, length);
        } while (tcpclientSite.Available > 0);
        byte[] dataRec = ms.ToArray();
        if (dataRec.Length != 0) streamBrowser.Write(dataRec, 0, dataRec.Length);
    }
}
```

Basically it just reads everything available on browser stream, sends it to site, reads everything available on site stream, sends it to browser, pretty simple.
However it works in the same thread, not in parallel, so I wanted to create separate thread before while(true), pass both tcpclients and networkstreams into this thread and make while(true) there with one of do{} cycles there, like this (pseudocode):

```
class Original {
    CreateNewThread();
    while(true) {
        ReadFromBrowser();
        SendToSite();
    }
}

class NewThread {
    while(true) {
        ReadFromSite();
        SendToBrowser();
    }
}
```

I did it and it just stopped working. As far as I understand, streamSite.Read() inside thread just do not read any data, even if some data was sent to site already.
I also checked if it will work if I just do both do{}'s in the same thread I just created - it works.
One thing I noticed that it hangs while preforming TLS handshake.
**Does reading and writing to browser and website is not allowed in separate threads or it's a mistake somewhere else?**

Comment: Looks like first class blocks so it stays in the while loop and never exits.  You never get to execute second code.  You need to run asynchronously so both classes run.

Comment: @jdweng, well, in theory it shouldn't because I run second class before first and from that moment both while(true)'s run in separate threads.

Comment: Type `byte[]` isn't really a thread safe type. How is the multi-thread access to shared resources is managed ?

Comment: Then you are stuck in the second class and never get to the first class.  Where are you running the two sets of close Asynchronously?

Comment: @jdweng, note that when both do{}'s in the same threads, everything works prefectly fine - it's never stuck in one of two using(){} because if there is no data to read, it just skips to second part of code. Problem occurs when I place one of using(){}'s in separate thread.

Comment: @Fabjan, shared resources are only tcpclientBrowser, tcpclientSite (both tcpClients) and streamBrowser, streamSite (both NetworkStreams that I basically get from tcpclients). In the current state it's not managed, but I tried to put both streams in lock(){} statement so only one thread access stream at time but it changed nothing.

Comment: The code that is working loops forever doing  a read and then a write.  The code that doesn't work just constantly reads from site and writes to browser.  Never writes to site.  If it gets to the write section of the code it is waiting for data from browser.  Where is code to write from browser?